# Get blue colored contours using scikit-image/opencv

Tags: opencv, scikit-image

I'm trying to get blue colored contours using scikit-image. I'm sure there are functions in opencv that are also available in scikit-image.

I am aware of the find_contours method which works well however it gets ALL colors of contours. I just wnat to get the blue contours.

http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.measure.find_contours.html

Any ideas of how to do this? My guess is to preprocess the image somehow to remove every color other than blue.

Comment: You could use [inRange()](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html) which checks if array elements lie between the elements of two other arrays, before that it's better to convert HSV color space as it is preferred  color space in color based segmentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your suggestion of first suppressing all other colors is a good one.  Here's some code for doing that:

```
from skimage import io, color, exposure, img_as_float
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# http://www.publicdomainpictures.net/view-image.php?image=26890&picture=color-wheel
image = img_as_float(io.imread('color-wheel.jpg'))

blue_lab = color.rgb2lab([[[0, 0, 1.]]])
light_blue_lab = color.rgb2lab([[[0, 1, 1.]]])
red_lab = color.rgb2lab([[[1, 0, 0.]]])
image_lab = color.rgb2lab(image)

distance_blue = color.deltaE_cmc(blue_lab, image_lab, kL=0.5, kC=0.5)
distance_light_blue = color.deltaE_cmc(light_blue_lab, image_lab, kL=0.5, kC=0.5)
distance_red = color.deltaE_cmc(red_lab, image_lab, kL=0.5, kC=0.5)
distance = distance_blue + distance_light_blue - distance_red
distance = exposure.rescale_intensity(distance)

image_blue = image.copy()
image_blue[distance > 0.3] = 0

f, (ax0, ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 3, figsize=(20, 10))
ax0.imshow(image)
ax1.imshow(distance, cmap='gray')
ax2.imshow(image_blue)
plt.show()
```

[image: Color selection]

Comment: Thank you! Just a side question: \Do you know how to get the contour area as well?

Comment: I'm not sure what "contour area" means?  You mean the area inside of the contour?

Comment: Yes, the area inside the contour

Comment: If you have the contour as a set of coordinates, then use the standard area-of-a-polygon formula: Calculating the area and centroid of a polygon - http://paulbourke.net/geometry/polygonmesh/

Comment: Also, one more question: Is there a way to 'combine' found contours? For example, I am getting a lot of small nearby contours which actually should be all one contour. Is there a way to group close contours together?

Comment: You can choose larger skips in level, otherwise you'd have to do a comparison of the contours, figure out how close they are (e.g. Hausdorff distance), and then take e.g. the mean shape of those contours as a representative.