# Scikit image color filtering and changing parts of image to array

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, scikit-image, omr

I want to do some Optical Mark Recognition using scikit-image. I am looking for 2 functions

Lets say I have an image that looks like this:[image: OMR]

The way I would detect it is using filters to clean the image:
(ie bilateral and Gaussian filtering for noise specks in `filter` module)

Then I would use a gray-scaling in `color` module
Third I would use a canny edge detector in `filter` module

I am trying to find out what do I use to filter the cells by color so I can mark reds and blues apart?

I am guessing there is some function for Hues, saturation, and brightness or RGB that can be used to filter out specific colors or some thing that can be used with `k-means` from `scikit learn` for filtering data

Second is how would I transform this image to an numpy array/pandas dataframe which will be the following:

```
[[1,2,0,2,0]
[0,1,1,0,1]
[0,0,1,2,0]]
```

Where red is 1, blue is 2, and white is 0. I have seen some people put a line that goes down it but do not know what it is called or if it is available in sk-image.

Comment: Do you know the positions of the circles beforehand?

Comment: @StefanvanderWalt Nope you would not. The positions you know would be the black circles

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The following code makes use of scikit-image's peak detector, applied on a distance map computed between the image and the values of pure red and blue:

```
from skimage import io, color, img_as_float
from skimage.feature import corner_peaks, plot_matches

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

image = img_as_float(io.imread('colordots.jpg'))

black_mask = color.rgb2gray(image) < 0.1
distance_red = color.rgb2gray(1 - np.abs(image - (1, 0, 0)))
distance_blue = color.rgb2gray(1 - np.abs(image - (0, 0, 1)))

distance_red[black_mask] = 0
distance_blue[black_mask] = 0

coords_red = corner_peaks(distance_red, threshold_rel=0.9, min_distance=50)
coords_blue = corner_peaks(distance_blue, threshold_rel=0.9, min_distance=50)

f, ((ax0, ax1), (ax2, ax3)) = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(15, 10))
ax0.imshow(image)
ax0.set_title('Input image')
ax1.imshow(image)
ax1.set_title('Marker locations')
ax1.plot(coords_red[:, 1], coords_red[:, 0], 'ro')
ax1.plot(coords_blue[:, 1], coords_blue[:, 0], 'bo')
ax1.axis('image')
ax2.imshow(distance_red, interpolation='nearest', cmap='gray')
ax2.set_title('Distance to pure red')
ax3.imshow(distance_blue, interpolation='nearest', cmap='gray')
ax3.set_title('Distance to pure blue')
plt.show()
```

[image: Color dot detection]

Comment: What version of Skimage do you have I do not have the `plot_matches` function in `skimage.feature`

Comment: I have the latest version.  Check ``skimage.__version__`` to see yours--what is it?

By the way, I realized that my method for finding the distance to blue was a bit crude.  A much better option would be to use the ``color.deltaE_*`` functions.

Comment: I am using 0.93. So for your code I am guessing what is happening is you first apply a mask for only the black. Then you apply filters for each color by subtracting everything not in their RGB value from 1. After that you added the black mask as a boundary to each color and used the corner detector to give coordinates of where each item is.

Comment: Almost: I got a mask to suppress the black circles, then measured the distance from the image's colors to both red and blue (this is where the ``color.deltaE_*`` functions would come in handy, see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21618252/get-blue-colored-contours-using-scikit-image-opencv/21661395#21661395).  I then find the peaks in those two distance maps separately, and that tells me where the blue and red dots are.

Comment: Hello excellent response I don't get what this line is doing:
`color.rgb2gray(1 - np.abs(image - (1, 0, 0)))`

 how we decide the tuples  (1, 0, 0) and  (0, 0, 1)?

Comment: `(1, 0, 0)` is pure red, `(0, 0, 1)` is pure blue (the images are in floating point format, so values range between 0 and 1).